# Looking for an efficient way to manipulate JSON data

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I have been parsing some JSON files and have eventually ended up with a dictionary with strings as keys and a list of tuples as a the value.

The `dict` has the following format:

```
str1: [(int1, bool), (int2, bool), ... ],
str2: [(int1, bool), (int2, bool), (int3, bool), ... ],
...
strN ...
```

What I want to achieve is a table that looks something like that:

```
      int1   int2  int3
str1  bool   bool
str2  bool   bool  bool
```

Is there any way to do that without writing a long algorithm with dozen on nested fors and ifs? Not asking to write that for me but just a hint into a correct direction.

I just want  to know how to manipulate the data into a similar format. It would be great though, if it was compatible writing it into a CSV or, ideally an, Excel file.

Comment: Are those actually _strings_, and you're asking how to parse them into tuples of lists of tuples, or do you already have tuples of lists of tuples and you're asking how to map that into a table?

Comment: Have you actually tried to write some code yourself?

Comment: @abarnert Hi, the data already has the structure that described above (first code section).

Comment: @JamesMills No, I didn't. That's why I mentioned that I want a hint into a right direction, not writing it for me. Just looking for idea.

Comment: @EugeneS: Your clarification about the data doesn't entirely make it clear. Do you have already-parsed python objects that look like this, or just strings with a regular structure? If you have actual Python objects, can you print them and edit into your post? It's not really clear if `str1` and `str2` are dictionary keys or items in a tuple.

Comment: @Marius you are right, I didn't explain myself properly. The data structure that I have is basically a dictionary with strings as keys and list of tuples as a value. I have updated that in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Will be great to know why the downvote

Comment: Looks like a silent downvoter swept through haha. I will upvote the question and suggest an edit to improve it. It isn't a bad question but needs some clarification. I will suggest to remove irrelevant data.

Answer (score 3):

If you've parsed the JSON into `data` that looks like

```
data = {
    'str1': [('int1', 'bool'), ('int2', 'bool')],
    'str2': [('int1', 'bool'), ('int2', 'bool'), ('int3', 'bool')] }
```

then you could load it into a [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrame with

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({key:pd.Series(dict(seq)) for key, seq in data.items()}).T
```

so that

```
print(df)
```

yields

```
      int1  int2  int3
str1  bool  bool   NaN
str2  bool  bool  bool
```

and

```
df.to_csv('/tmp/out.csv')
```

produces a CSV with contents

```
,int1,int2,int3
str1,bool,bool,
str2,bool,bool,bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're parsing lines and rows, if you need to walk through them - for checking or processing purposes, by example - any algorithm will run in `lines*rows` items, in average.

Now, if you're not worried too much about performance but about readability, you can separate your parsing into some functions with clear names that complete some small step of the operation. Even if some functions will *only* be an for loop extracted, it will improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty straight forward, so;

- Import a library for JSON parsing
- Import a library for CSV writing

Then, parse the JSON into a data structure (presumably a `map` or `list` with an `array`) and write it out into CSV by parsing that data structure in.

*If the data structure doesn't comply to produce your required format then use a simple `for loop` that will modify and convert the data structure.*

To address efficiency;

- Using libraries will usually give good efficiency with general cases compared to writing your very first parser or writer.
- Containing any data manipulation to a small loop sandwiched between the parsing and writing stage should allow you to keep your core algorithm easily recognizable, readable and thus, hopefully, result in it being efficient.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but that's not really answer my question. I know how to import json and csv libraries and I know how to use them. In fact I already have the above structure that I parsed from json file. I just ask about a way to convert that structure into a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you have is already parsed into tuples of lists of tuples, what you're asking is how to group them into a table.

One obvious way to store a 2D table with sparse axes is with a dict, keyed off the `int` and `str` values. For example:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
seen_ints = set()
for s, pairs in rows:
    for i, b in pairs:
        d[s][i] = b
        seen_ints.add(i)
```

Now, to get the rows, you just iterate `d[s].items()`. Or, if you want them in sorted order of the strings, iterate `sorted(d[s].items())`. Each row is a dict; to get the columns in your desired order, you just access `row[key] for key in seen_ints`. (If you want the columns sorted too, just do `seen_ints = sorted(seen_ints)` before the outer loop.)

Or you can use `csv.DictWriter` to drop the `seen_ints` set and just write out each row `dict` as a CSV row.